# What happens if I can't pay money to my health insurance company?

Tags: united-states, health-insurance, healthcare

I have a health issue for which I have to go into  treatment for 4 to 6 weeks.
When I called my insurance about the benefits, I was told that after treatment, I will owe $5000 to my insurance company after they pay my benefits to the treatment facility.

What happens if I can't pay the $5000 to my insurance company after my treatment?

P.S. I have no money to pay and I am under my parent's health plan.

Comment: Are you sure you were told you would owe money to the insurer and not your provider (doctor/facility)?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you're talking about your deductible. A deductible is a threshold over which the insurance company will cover all costs. You need to cover any values below the deductible. If you have a $1000 bill, your insurance won't kick in. If you have a $5000 bill, your insurance won't kick in. If you have a $500,000 bill, your insurance will pay $495,000 (assuming you're covered for that much), but you will have to pay the first $5000.

If you cannot pay your deductible, the insurance company is unlikely to pay out the rest. It's pretty important that you secure that money so that you're able to benefit from your insurance. I'm not familiar with all of the services available to citizens of the USA (which I assume you are), but I would reach out to family.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a discussion with the medical provider. Depending on the policy requirements and the procedures involved, you may have to pay some or all of the $5,000 before all the procedure has been completed. In some cases they don't charge you at the beginning, and will wait for the insurance company to receive the bills, and then pay their portion. In other cases they charge you a copay up front.

The medical provider might charge you interest if you don't pay your portion within 30 or 60 days of the treatment. They also might workout a payment plan.

Comment: I have never had to pay the insurance company. I have always had to pay the doctor, orthodontist, hospital...It hasn't mattered if it was a copay or a deductible. The only thing that differed was the timing.